# form not updating itself using multiple steps URLS

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am editing a questionnaire app using a diplay_by_question template where each question is displayed on a single page using a different URL in the form of survey/22; suvey/22-1; survey/22-2 ....

When saving the answers the form should take the actual step we are in and save it in the database.

For example if I am at URL survey/22-2 is referencing to survey ID: 22 and step : 1

In my code it shoud extract from my form the data using the current step:

```
form = ResponseForm(request.POST, survey=survey, user=request.user, step=kwargs.get('step', 0))
```

However I do not understand why if the URL is step 1 the step does not update and stay at step 0
Could you please help ?

viexs.py:

```
class SurveyDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, is_published=True, id=kwargs['id'])
        if survey.template is not None and len(survey.template) > 4:
            template_name = survey.template
        else:
            if survey.display_by_question:
                template_name = 'survey/survey.html'
            else:
                template_name = 'survey/one_page_survey.html'
        if survey.need_logged_user and not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
        categories = Category.objects.filter(survey=survey).order_by('order')
        form = ResponseForm(survey=survey, user=request.user,
                            step=kwargs.get('step', 0))
        context = {
            'response_form': form,
            'survey': survey,
            'categories': categories,
        }

        return render(request, template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, is_published=True, id=kwargs['id'])
        if survey.need_logged_user and not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
        form = ResponseForm(request.POST, survey=survey, user=request.user, step=kwargs.get('step', 0))
        context = {'response_form': form, 'survey': survey,}
        if form.is_valid():
            session_key = 'survey_%s' % (kwargs['id'],)
            if session_key not in request.session:
                request.session[session_key] = {}
            for key, value in form.cleaned_data.items():
                request.session[session_key][key] = value
                request.session.modified = True

            next_url = form.next_step_url()
            response = None
            if survey.display_by_question:
                save_form = form
                if save_form.is_valid():
                    response = save_form.save()
            else:
                response = form.save()

            if next_url is not None:
                return redirect(next_url)
            else:
                del request.session[session_key]
                if response is None:
                    return redirect('/')
                else:
                    next_ = request.session.get('next', None)
                    if next_ is not None:
                        if 'next' in request.session:
                            del request.session['next']
                        return redirect(next_)
                    else:
                        return redirect('survey-confirmation',
                                        uuid=response.interview_uuid)
        if survey.template is not None and len(survey.template) > 4:
            template_name = survey.template
        else:
            if survey.display_by_question:
                template_name = 'survey/survey.html'
            else:
                template_name = 'survey/one_page_survey.html'
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

form.py:

```
class ResponseForm(models.ModelForm):

    WIDGETS = {
        Question.TEXT: forms.Textarea,
        Question.SHORT_TEXT: forms.TextInput,
        Question.RADIO: forms.RadioSelect,
        Question.SELECT: forms.Select,
        Question.SELECT_IMAGE: ImageSelectWidget,
        Question.SELECT_MULTIPLE: forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    }

    class Meta(object):
        model = Response
        fields = ()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        """ Expects a survey object to be passed in initially """
        self.survey = kwargs.pop('survey')
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        try:
            self.step = int(kwargs.pop('step'))
        except KeyError:
            self.step = None
        super(ResponseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4().hex
        self.steps_count = len(self.survey.questions.all())
        # add a field for each survey question, corresponding to the question
        # type as appropriate.
        data = kwargs.get('data')
        for i, question in enumerate(self.survey.questions.all()):
            is_current_step = i != self.step and self.step is not None
            if self.survey.display_by_question and is_current_step:
                continue
            else:
                self.add_question(question, data)

    def _get_preexisting_response(self):
        """ Recover a pre-existing response in database.
        The user must be logged.
        :rtype: Response or None"""
        if not self.user.is_authenticated():
            return None
        try:
            return Response.objects.get(user=self.user, survey=self.survey)
        except Response.DoesNotExist:
            LOGGER.debug("No saved response for '%s' for user %s",
                         self.survey, self.user)
            return None

    def _get_preexisting_answer(self, question):
        """ Recover a pre-existing answer in database.
        The user must be logged. A Response containing the Answer must exists.
        :param Question question: The question we want to recover in the
        response.
        :rtype: Answer or None"""
        response = self._get_preexisting_response()
        if response is None:
            return None
        try:
            return Answer.objects.get(question=question, response=response)
        except Answer.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_question_initial(self, question, data):
        """ Get the initial value that we should use in the Form
        :param Question question: The question
        :param dict data: Value from a POST request.
        :rtype: String or None  """
        initial = None
        answer = self._get_preexisting_answer(question)
        if answer:
            # Initialize the field with values from the database if any
            if question.type == Question.SELECT_MULTIPLE:
                initial = []
                if answer.body == "[]":
                    pass
                elif "[" in answer.body and "]" in answer.body:
                    initial = []
                    unformated_choices = answer.body[1:-1].strip()
                    for unformated_choice in unformated_choices.split(","):
                        choice = unformated_choice.split("'")[1]
                        initial.append(slugify(choice))
                else:
                    # Only one element
                    initial.append(slugify(answer.body))
            else:
                initial = answer.body
        if data:
            # Initialize the field field from a POST request, if any.
            # Replace values from the database
            initial = data.get('question_%d' % question.pk)
        return initial

    def get_question_widget(self, question):
        """ Return the widget we should use for a question.
        :param Question question: The question
        :rtype: django.forms.widget or None """
        try:
            return self.WIDGETS[question.type]
        except KeyError:
            return None

    def get_question_choices(self, question):
        """ Return the choices we should use for a question.
        :param Question question: The question
        :rtype: List of String or None """
        qchoices = None
        if question.type not in [Question.TEXT, Question.SHORT_TEXT,
                                 Question.INTEGER]:
            qchoices = question.get_choices()
            # add an empty option at the top so that the user has to explicitly
            # select one of the options
            if question.type in [Question.SELECT, Question.SELECT_IMAGE]:
                qchoices = tuple([('', '-------------')]) + qchoices
        return qchoices

    def get_question_field(self, question, **kwargs):
        """ Return the field we should use in our form.
        :param Question question: The question
        :param **kwargs: A dict of parameter properly initialized in
            add_question.
        :rtype: django.forms.fields """
        FIELDS = {
            Question.TEXT: forms.CharField,
            Question.SHORT_TEXT: forms.CharField,
            Question.SELECT_MULTIPLE: forms.MultipleChoiceField,
            Question.INTEGER: forms.IntegerField
        }
        # logging.debug("Args passed to field %s", kwargs)
        try:
            return FIELDS[question.type](**kwargs)
        except KeyError:
            return forms.ChoiceField(**kwargs)

    def add_question(self, question, data):
        """ Add a question to the form.
        :param Question question: The question to add.
        :param dict data: The pre-existing values from a post request. """
        kwargs = {"label": question.text,
                  "required": question.required, }
        initial = self.get_question_initial(question, data)
        if initial:
            kwargs["initial"] = initial
        choices = self.get_question_choices(question)
        if choices:
            kwargs["choices"] = choices
        widget = self.get_question_widget(question)
        if widget:
            kwargs["widget"] = widget
        field = self.get_question_field(question, **kwargs)
        if question.category:
            field.widget.attrs["category"] = question.category.name
        else:
            field.widget.attrs["category"] = ""
        # logging.debug("Field for %s : %s", question, field.__dict__)
        self.fields['question_%d' % question.pk] = field

    def has_next_step(self):
        if self.survey.display_by_question:
            if self.step < self.steps_count - 1:
                return True
        return False

    def next_step_url(self):
        if self.has_next_step():
            context = {'id': self.survey.id, 'step': self.step + 1}
            return reverse('survey-detail-step', kwargs=context)
        else:
            return None

    def current_step_url(self):
        return reverse('survey-detail-step', kwargs={'id': self.survey.id, 'step': self.step})

    def save(self, commit=True):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        """ Save the response object """
        # Recover an existing response from the database if any
        #  There is only one response by logged user.
        response = self._get_preexisting_response()
        if response is None:
            response = super(ResponseForm, self).save(commit=False)
        response.survey = self.survey
        response.interview_uuid = self.uuid
        if self.user.is_authenticated():
            response.user = self.user
        response.save()
        # response "raw" data as dict (for signal)
        data = {
            'survey_id': response.survey.id,
            'interview_uuid': response.interview_uuid,
            'responses': []
        }
        # create an answer object for each question and associate it with this
        # response.
        for field_name, field_value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            if field_name.startswith("question_"):
                # warning: this way of extracting the id is very fragile and
                # entirely dependent on the way the question_id is encoded in
                # the field name in the __init__ method of this form class.
                q_id = int(field_name.split("_")[1])
                question = Question.objects.get(pk=q_id)
                answer = self._get_preexisting_answer(question)
                if answer is None:
                    answer = Answer(question=question)
                    answer.body = field_value
                    data['responses'].append((answer.question.id, answer.body))
                    LOGGER.debug(
                        "Creating answer for question %d of type %s : %s", q_id,
                        answer.question.type, field_value
                        )
                    answer.response = response
                    answer.save()


        survey_completed.send(sender=Response, instance=response, data=data)
        return response
```

Comment: Are you sure that your URL pattern is correct and setting `kwargs['step']` to `1`?

Comment: I guess so this is my url il looks ok : url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)-(?P<step>\d+)/', SurveyDetail.as_view(),
        name='survey-detail-step'),